# Problem related to multinomial expansion.

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem, multinomial-distribution

How do I expand $(a_1+a_2+a_3+.....+a_k)^3$ where $a_i \in \Bbb R $ for  $i = 1,2,...,k $?

Comment: Literally expand it or use induction for a slightly easier task.

Comment: @Vlad thats the problem I dont understand how do i expand. Can u elaborate?

Comment: I made a mistake wait

Comment: Now it is correct. i edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

$$(a_1+a_2+...+a_k)^3=(a_1+a_2+...+a_k)\cdot(a_1+a_2+...+a_k)^2=(a_1+a_2+...+a_k)\cdot\big(\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i^2+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq k}a_ia_j\big)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i^3+3\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq k}a_ia_j(a_i+a_j)+6\sum_{1\leq i<j<l\leq k}a_ia_ja_l$$